# making use of self encrypting SSD

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm

Is something special needed?

It is in a supermicro server having a AOM-TPM-9670V-S TPM 2.0 and a Broadcom/Avago MegaRAID 9361-24i card.

Trying to use some Seagate Nytro SAS self encrypting SSD's;  in the megaraid setup it identifies the disk as encryption capable, and in the supermicro bios I can tab over to *security* and see the TPM stuff but that seems to be as far as I can get.

and system will be running RHEL linux, not Windows, if that matters; Am I correct in thinking this *self-encryption* stuff will be independent of the operating system?